# listView transparente

Tags: android, listview

Estoy intentando que mi `listview` y por tanto los item que lo forman tengan fondo transparente para que se pueda ver el fondo del layout sobre el que se encuentra el listView
he probado a poner en el listview y en el layout del item esto pero no hay manera:

```
android:background="@null"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="#00000000"
```

alguna idea más?

Comment: sólo usa `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` y también asegúrate que en tus rows o items; como los quieras llamar, también tengan el color `transparent`

Comment: buenas, he probado cada una por separado y no hay manera, estaba buscando una cuarta forma, aunque sea con código java

Comment: agrega el layout completo que contiene el ListView. @user2070274

Comment: Es raro con sólo agregar transparent funcionaría, lo que podría pasar es que se te está escapando algo en tu código..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer un fondo transparente:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Buenas no me funciona, lo he puesto tanto en el listView como en el item, me parece muy extraño no sé